# Python Dictionaries | ZIP | dict(zip())

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a problem with python zip and dictionaries. I have list called dirs which contains all directory names. I want to generate something like the below one

```
dirs_count = {'placements':{'total':0,'Others':0},'x-force':{'total':0,'Others':0})
```

I used the following code to generate this.

```
dirs = ['placemetns', 'x-code']
dirs_count = dict(zip(dirs,[{'total':0, 'others': 0}]*len(dirs)))
# {'placements':{'total':0,'others':0},'x-code':{'total':0,'others':0}}
```

But the problem here is, if I modify one dictionary value, the following thing happens..

```
dirs_count['placements']['total'] = 5
# {'placements':{'total':5,'others':0},'x-code':{'total':5,'others':0}}
```

**Is there any way to prevent this?**

or

**Is there any way to generate dirs_count in which it doesn't effect the entier dictionary on modification?**

Comment: `[{'total':0, 'others': 0} for _ in dirs]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `dirs_count = {d: {'total': 0, 'others': 0} for d in dirs}`.

What happens in your case is that both `placements` and `x-code` refer to the same object.

Comment: Yea, I understood that it refers to the same object. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @7H3IN5ID3R - you didn't hint in your question that you know why it happens. This is a great solution to the problem, "pythonic", and much more straight forward than rigging some solution with `zip`.

Comment: Yea, that's my mistake. I didn't mention that in question. Actually I expected a solution - break the reference to the object and replicate the same objects and create new replications. But, it's not possible. My bad..!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `[{'total':0, 'others': 0}]*len(dirs)` gives you a number of references to the same dict, so any changes to one will affect all the copies. try instead

```
dirs = ['placemetns', 'x-code']
dicts = [{'total':0, 'others': 0} for i in dirs]
dirs_count = dict(zip(dirs,dicts))
```